# Build suite: "configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh tool/config.sub"

Tags: ruby

I try to compile the Ruby interpreter inside a virgin virtual box. I installed FreeBSD, pulled Ruby from Github and followed the instructions in `README.md`. The `./configure` step gives me the message:

```
% ./configure
checking for ruby... false
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh tool/config.sub
```

I found by Google that this problem surfaces again and again over several years, but the old solutions
don't help me. For example, an `autoreconf --install` didn't solve the issue.

The file `tool/config.sub` doesn't exist.

What can I do next?

Thanks in advance, Bertram

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

To build Ruby from the Git repo there must be already an installed version of Ruby.

This does not apply to the .tar.gz archives you can download from the Ruby site.